# Getting text of clicked button in a listActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android ListActivity that creates multiple buttons (from a database source) via layout inflator:

```
private class QuestAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Quests> {
        private ArrayList<Quests> quests;
        public QuestAdaptor(Context context,
                                                                   int textViewResourceId,
                                                                   ArrayList<Quests> items) {
                  super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
                  this.quests = items;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.quests, null);
                }
                Quests o = quests.get(position);
                TextView qt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quest_title);
                TextView qpr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quest_price);
                TextView qp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quest_points);
                TextView btn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_quest);
                qt.setText(o.title);
                qpr.setText(o.dollar_price);
                qp.setText(o.pts);
                btn.setText(o.quest_id);
                return v;
        }
```

I also have a method for "onclick" defined in the xml layout:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_quest"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/quest_points"
        android:onClick="selectQuest"
        android:text="" />


public void selectQuest (View v){
        Button btn_select_quest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_select_quest);
        String buttonText = btn_select_quest.getText().toString();
        showToastMessage(buttonText);

      }
```

My problem is that the above code always returns "1" on clicking any button(the buttons are titled "1", "2", "3", etc). I guess im looking for something like this.getText().toString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using findviewbyid in SelectQuest use the v passed to the function

> String buttonText = v.getText().toString();

Comment: getText() isn't allowed for this